# Best way of mapping a Numeric(9,0) to int using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

In our sql server database we have columns of type Numeric(9,0).
When I create a model from the database these columns are given the type decimal in c#. However I can't see why we can't use int here. An int should be able to hold all the numbers in a numeric(9,0).

If I just try it with an int in the model like this:

```
public Model
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

I will get an this error:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Int32'.'

The way I've found to solve this is to "tell" EF about the column type in OnModelCreating like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Model>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnType("numeric(9, 0)");
            });
```

This seems to make it work fine.

What is the reason that this works and is this a correct way of doing it?

Comment: "An int should be able to hold all the numbers in a numeric(9,0)", nope. A numeric, according to [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) "[...] is functionally identical to decimal". Meaning this column can hold non-whole numbers (i.e 10.3), which an integer cannot represent. You'll probably want to change your Id column to an int anyways if you intend on only storing whole numbers

Comment: You're right that an int can't hold all the numbers held by a numeric. But I'm talking about the specific numeric Numeric(9,0). 
Unfortunately I'm not in charge of the database, so can't change the column type.

Comment: I see, then maybe you could use EF-Core's [value conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations) and explicitly tell it how to do the conversion

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get that working. But the solution I came up with that i described works fine. I'm curious to know why. And also if it seems like a good solution.

Comment: Under the hood it's likely a coversion and will likely overflow and fail. Where a converter you can explicitly deal with the overflow... your choice

Comment: Test it , see what happens

Comment: Also , I couldn't get it to work excuses, will fail senior dev code reviews on commits every time

Answer (score 0):

An int has somewhat less than 7 significant figures (+/- 2.2 billion). Your decimal has 9 significant figures.

Comment: As far as I know an int can be between  -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647
When I count it seems like that mean a bit more than 9 significant digits. Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?